# Побитовый сдвиг - умножает число на 2 C#

Tags: c#, битовые-операции

Нужно сделать побитовый сдвиг, но результат умножается на 2.

```
string bitRightOld = (RemoteControl).ToString("X4"); //Это я добавил для проверки
(RemoteControl >> 15).ToString("X4") //Побитовый сдвиг
```

`RemoteControl` = `18 153 472`. `bitRightOld` = `115 000`. После побитового сдвига должно получиться `277(115 в HEX)`, но выдается - `554(22A в HEX)`.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я не так делаю...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RemoteControl >> 15 = 554 // 15 раз разделить 18 153 472 на 2 - разделить на 32 768‬
RemoteControl >> 16 = 277 // 16 раз разделить 18 153 472 на 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сдвинуть на 16

```
RemoteControl >> 16
```

И почитайте пару статей про битовые сдвиги. Побалуйтесь с калькулятором, в котором есть режим программиста.